# How to clean my data, so that I can convert it into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file like shown below.
My question is, is there a way to clean the data without having to do it manually so that I can convert it into a data format like csv?

```
    Word, Hiragana, English
    会う, あう -to meet
    青, あお -blue
    青い, あおい -blue
    赤, あか -red
    赤い, あかい -red
    明い, あかるい -bright
    秋, あき -autumn
    開く, あく -to open,to become open
    開ける, あける -to open
    上げる, あげる -to give
    朝, あさ -morning
    朝御飯, あさごはん -breakfast
    あさって -day after tomorrow
    足, あし -foot,leg
    明日, あした -tomorrow
    あそこ -over there
    遊ぶ, あそぶ -to play,to make a visit
    暖かい, あたたかい -warm
    頭, あたま -head
    新しい, あたらしい -new
    あちら -there
    暑い, あつい -hot
    熱い, あつい -hot to the touch
    厚い, あつい -kind, deep, thick
    あっち -over there
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work in your case:

```
for l in textfile:
    split1 = l.split(',', 1) # split on first occurance  of ',' in line

    word = split1[0] # take the first argument of the split as word

    split2 = split1[0].split('-', 1) # split the second part with first occurance of '-'
    hiragana = split2[0]
    english = split2[1]
```